# How do i solve this equation for m using SciPy root function and how do i write it

Tags: python, scipy

````
```
import numpy as np

K = 1.38e-23
z = 8
J = 1.8e-21
T = 1
m = 0

```
````

these are just constants

```
  m = np.tanh((z*J*m)/(K*T))
```

this is the equation
but I need to find it each m value for each T value so I'm not sure if a nested loop would be better where I loop through T and m because I've tried and is doesn't work proper I'm just not sure what to do so any help would be great. also T is in range 1 - 1501

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Comment: It's not functional to tell us "I've tried and is doesn't work proper"  With no code and no problem specification, we can't do anything for your attempt.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Why `m` is on both sides here? `m = np.tanh((z*J*m)/(K*T))` might there should be other parameter? Please check it

Comment: Be careful with the presentation of the question as well, in the preview we can see the backticks which implies an error in the question markdown

Answer (score 0):

I am not still sure what you really need.

If you do some optimization to find some `min` or `max`, you should have a look again might you provide less information to us than needed (for example you say `m=0` but that gives answer 0 for any `T`. Might you want to have range of `m` and `T`. It's then another story.

Without scipy if you willing to calculate just a result of a function of two parameters, `m` and `T`, you can use `linspace` for example to set ranges and steps.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def func(T, m):
    z = 8
    K = 1.38e-23
    J = 1.8e-21
    return np.tanh((z*J*m)/(K*T))

xaxis = np.linspace(1, 1501, 1500)
yaxis = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
result = func(xaxis[:,None], yaxis[None,:])
plt.plot(result)
```

And you get smth as below, few curves. But I set m in range, might you need another values there. Up to you. Check and go.

[image]